# When should we use CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR

Tags: opencl

I am trying to understand when to use `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR` on a CPU-GPU Soc by Intel.

Reading [this guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/ioclsdk/2013/OG/Mapping_Memory_Objects_%28USE_HOST_PTR%29.htm) I came across:

> If your application uses a specific memory management algorithm, or if
>   you want to wrap existing native application memory allocations, you
>   can pass a pointer to clCreateBuffer along with the
>   CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR flag.

Can someone explain with an example what is the meaning of:  `specific memory management algorithm`, and  `wrap existing native application memory allocations`.

Answer (score 1):

CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR flag means, that memory for OpenCL memory object will not be allocated on Device side, but will be used from memory, allocated on Host side. Though, memory content may be cached (this is opaque to user).

Imagine, that you have complicated library, which has it's own sophisticated memory allocation mechanisms (e. g. with reference counting), etc. It's not that easy (usually - impossible) to allocate OpenCL memory objects "by hand", as they must have same lifetime to objects, allocated by library, (possibly - same alignment), etc.

In that case much easier way it to use CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR flag, when creating OpenCL memory objects. All objects handling will be done under-the-hood. This way can save you a lot of pain especially when you're working with big projects, implemented on plain C, in which memory objects processing is always tricky.